# Can I save a jade from root rot?

Tags: jade

So if I have 3 leaves growing in a pot, and 1 gets root rot, is it possible to save the other 2? And if so, how would this be achieved?

Comment: I've heard so many different things about adding rocks to the bottom of the pot what is your opinion about that?

Answer (score 3):

Many root rots are caused by a bacteria which takes hold if poor conditions are present like water logged soil.  In a small pot of seedlings which have less resources than an established plant it's likely that if one has root rot the others have

It does no harm to gently separate them into different pots with a free draining soil and good light and see what happens.